# Scrollable content on left - sticky image on right - with active item on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I have a design that looks like exactly the Webflow CMS slider, so it has a slider on the left side and images on the right, and the images changes depending on the item in the slider (which one is currently active) when scrolling

I tried to add a scroll event on the feature list

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var $featurewrap = $(".feature_sub-feature-wrap");
  var window_offset = $featurewrap .offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

[image]

But I have no idea what should I do when the scroll happens

Sample
https://webflow.com/cms (Connect dynamic content to any layout)

JS Bin for demo
https://jsbin.com/zijigawegi/edit?html,css,output

```css
a {
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.feature_list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.feature-list_cms {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  padding-right: 80px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.feature_sub-feature-wrap {
  padding-top: 15vh;
  padding-bottom: 15vh;
}

.feature_sub-feature-animate.w--current {
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.feature_sub-feature-animate {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1px;
  opacity: 0.15;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  cursor: default;
}
.w-inline-block {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cms-img-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.med-title.cc-small {
  width: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 130%;
}
.med-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.paragraph-gray {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  white-space: normal;
}


.feature_sub-feature-line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: auto;
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 1px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    background-color: #000;
}


.feature_sub-feature-wrap.cc-bottom {
    padding-bottom: 30vh;
}


.feature-list_visual-track-copy {
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
}

.feature-alt_visual-wrap {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 12vh;
    padding-top: 30px;
}


.feature-alt_visual {
    position: relative;
    height: 76vh;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
}


.feature_cover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
}

.feature-visual.w--current {
    opacity: 1;
}
.feature-visual {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature_list">
   <div class="feature-list_cms">
      <div id="b-1" class="feature_sub-feature-wrap">
         <a href="#b-1" class="feature_sub-feature-animate w-inline-block w--current">
            <div class="cms-img-mobile"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 87vw, (max-width: 767px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 87vw, 100vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg 1200w" alt=""></div>
            <h2 class="med-title cc-small">Connect dynamic content to any layout</h2>
            <p class="paragraph-gray">You’re not locked into any layout — simply add the elements you want and pull in the data from your CMS.<br></p>
            <div class="feature_sub-feature-line"></div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div id="b-2" class="feature_sub-feature-wrap">
         <div class="cms-img-mobile"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 87vw, (max-width: 767px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 87vw, 100vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg 1200w" alt=""></div>
         <a href="#b-2" class="feature_sub-feature-animate w-inline-block">
            <h2 class="med-title cc-small">Filter what you display</h2>
            <p class="paragraph-gray">Conditionally display content as needed, sort based on a given field, or hide content you don’t need.<br></p>
            <div class="feature_sub-feature-line"></div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div id="b-3" class="feature_sub-feature-wrap cc-bottom">
         <div class="cms-img-mobile"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 87vw, (max-width: 767px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 87vw, 100vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg 1200w" alt=""></div>
         <a href="#b-3" class="feature_sub-feature-animate w-inline-block">
            <h2 class="med-title cc-small">Build a custom search experience from scratch</h2>
            <p class="paragraph-gray">Design your search experience from scratch — visually — and control exactly what content your site visitors can discover.<br></p>
            <div class="feature_sub-feature-line"></div>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="feature-list_visual-track-copy">
      <div class="feature-alt_visual-wrap">
         <div class="feature-alt_visual">
            <div class="feature_cover"></div>
           
            <a href="#b-1" class="feature-visual cc-b5 w-inline-block w--current">
              <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, 48vw" 
                   srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-500.jpeg 500w, 
                           https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-800.jpeg 800w, 
                           https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, 
                           https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg 1200w" alt="" class="feature-image cc-cms"></a>
           
           <a href="#b-2" class="feature-visual cc-b6 w-inline-block"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, 48vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg 1200w" alt="" class="feature-image cc-cms"></a><a href="#b-3" class="feature-visual cc-b3 w-inline-block"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, 48vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg 1200w" alt="" class="feature-image cc-cms"></a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Where is the code that handles the scroll event?

Comment: It is included in the question. basically I want the same behavior the link I sent (Webflow)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect when an element enters and exits the viewport. Here's a minimal reproducible example, you'll have to apply this technique to your own code.

```js
const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('section div'));
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('aside img');

function detectIntersection(entries) {
  for (let e of entries) {
    let i = items.indexOf(e.target);
    if (e.isIntersecting) {
      requestAnimationFrame(ts => {
        e.target.classList.add('visible');
        imgs[i].classList.add('visible');
      });
    } else {
      e.target.classList.remove('visible');
      imgs[i].classList.remove('visible');
    }
  }
}

const options = {
  threshold: 0.25
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  detectIntersection, options
);

items.forEach(i => observer.observe(i));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

section {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

section div,
aside img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

section div {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

aside {
  position: relative;
}

aside img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div> test 1 </div>
    <div> test 2 </div>
    <div> test 3 </div>
    <div> test 4 </div>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?4">
  </aside>
</main>
```

The `threshold` option specifies how much of the element needs to be visible before triggering the callback. Values range from 0 to 1, so 0.25 means 25% percent must be visible which seems to be a good number for scrolling but you may need to adjust this based on your content and transition-duration.

Answer (score 1):

A Pure JS  solution is to use a combination of `offsetTop`  (return element position in absolute value) and  `window.pageYOffsetTop` (return window position in absolute value).

Few tips:

1. `offsetTop` return the `top:0` relative to viewpoints, so adding
   `window.innerHeight * 0.5` make it relative to the center.
2. There is no `offsetBottom` in JS, but `offsetTop + offsetHeight` do
   the job
3. Add `!important` to css to add specifity.

`elements.forEach((ele, i) => i !== 0 ? ele.style.opacity = 0.15 : ele.style.opacity = 1)` is not needed when you implement in your code. It is for improving reability (make only first item `opaciity:1`)

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".feature_sub-feature-wrap")
let index;
elements.forEach((ele,i)=>i !== 0 ? ele.style.opacity = 0.15 : ele.style.opacity =1)
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){

for(let i =0;i<elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].classList.remove("active")
    const window_height = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight * 0.5;
    const offsetBottom = elements[i].offsetTop + elements[i].offsetHeight
elements[i].classList.remove("active")
if(window_height>=elements[i].offsetTop && window_height <= offsetBottom ){
index =i
}
} 
elements.forEach((ele,i)=>i !== index ? ele.style.opacity = 0.15 : ele.style.opacity =1);
})
```

```css
a {
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.feature_list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.feature-list_cms {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  padding-right: 80px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.feature_sub-feature-wrap {
  padding-top: 15vh;
  padding-bottom: 15vh;
        border: red 2px solid ;
}

.feature_sub-feature-animate.w--current {
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.feature_sub-feature-animate {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1px;
  opacity: 0.15;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  cursor: default;
}
.w-inline-block {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cms-img-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.med-title.cc-small {
  width: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 130%;
}
.med-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.paragraph-gray {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  white-space: normal;
}


.feature_sub-feature-line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: auto;
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 1px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    background-color: #000;
}


.feature_sub-feature-wrap.cc-bottom {
    padding-bottom: 30vh;
}


.feature-list_visual-track-copy {
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
}

.feature-alt_visual-wrap {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 12vh;
    padding-top: 30px;
}


.feature-alt_visual {
    position: relative;
    height: 76vh;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
}


.feature_cover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
}

.feature-visual.w--current {
    opacity: 1;
}
.feature-visual {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.active {
opacity:1 !important;


}
```

```html
<div class="feature_list">
   <div class="feature-list_cms">
      <div id="b-1" class="feature_sub-feature-wrap">
         <a href="#b-1" class="feature_sub-feature-animate w-inline-block w--current">
            <div class="cms-img-mobile"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 87vw, (max-width: 767px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 87vw, 100vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg 1200w" alt=""></div>
            <h2 class="med-title cc-small">Connect dynamic content to any layout</h2>
            <p class="paragraph-gray">You’re not locked into any layout — simply add the elements you want and pull in the data from your CMS.<br></p>
            <div class="feature_sub-feature-line"></div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div id="b-2" class="feature_sub-feature-wrap">
         <div class="cms-img-mobile"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 87vw, (max-width: 767px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 87vw, 100vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg 1200w" alt=""></div>
         <a href="#b-2" class="feature_sub-feature-animate w-inline-block">
            <h2 class="med-title cc-small">Filter what you display</h2>
            <p class="paragraph-gray">Conditionally display content as needed, sort based on a given field, or hide content you don’t need.<br></p>
            <div class="feature_sub-feature-line"></div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div id="b-3" class="feature_sub-feature-wrap cc-bottom">
         <div class="cms-img-mobile"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 87vw, (max-width: 767px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 87vw, 100vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg 1200w" alt=""></div>
         <a href="#b-3" class="feature_sub-feature-animate w-inline-block">
            <h2 class="med-title cc-small">Build a custom search experience from scratch</h2>
            <p class="paragraph-gray">Design your search experience from scratch — visually — and control exactly what content your site visitors can discover.<br></p>
            <div class="feature_sub-feature-line"></div>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="feature-list_visual-track-copy">
      <div class="feature-alt_visual-wrap">
         <div class="feature-alt_visual">
            <div class="feature_cover"></div>
           
            <a href="#b-1" class="feature-visual cc-b5 w-inline-block w--current">
              <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, 48vw" 
                   srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-500.jpeg 500w, 
                           https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-800.jpeg 800w, 
                           https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, 
                           https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg 1200w" alt="" class="feature-image cc-cms"></a>
           
           <a href="#b-2" class="feature-visual cc-b6 w-inline-block"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, 48vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg 1200w" alt="" class="feature-image cc-cms"></a><a href="#b-3" class="feature-visual cc-b3 w-inline-block"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, 48vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg 1200w" alt="" class="feature-image cc-cms"></a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Updated version:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".feature_sub-feature-wrap")
let index;
elements.forEach((ele, i) => i !== 0 ? ele.style.opacity = 0.15 : ele.style.opacity = 1)
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (check(elements[i]) && index !== i ) {
        elements.forEach((ele, i) => {
        ele.style.opacity = 0.15;
        ele.classList.remove("active")
  } );
       index = i
       elements[i].classList.add('active')    
  }
  }

})



function check(ele){
    const window_height = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight * 0.5;
    const offsetBottom = ele.offsetTop + ele.offsetHeight
 
    if (window_height >= ele.offsetTop && window_height <= offsetBottom) return true;
    return false;

}
```

```css
a {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.feature_list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.feature-list_cms {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  padding-right: 80px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.feature_sub-feature-wrap {
  padding-top: 15vh;
  padding-bottom: 15vh;
  border: red 2px solid;
}

.feature_sub-feature-animate.w--current {
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}

.feature_sub-feature-animate {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 1px;
  opacity: 0.15;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  cursor: default;
}

.w-inline-block {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cms-img-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.med-title.cc-small {
  width: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 130%;
}

.med-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.paragraph-gray {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  white-space: normal;
}

.feature_sub-feature-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: auto;
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.feature_sub-feature-wrap.cc-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 30vh;
}

.feature-list_visual-track-copy {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}

.feature-alt_visual-wrap {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 12vh;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.feature-alt_visual {
  position: relative;
  height: 76vh;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

.feature_cover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}

.feature-visual.w--current {
  opacity: 1;
}

.feature-visual {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature_list">
  <div class="feature-list_cms">
    <div id="b-1" class="feature_sub-feature-wrap">
      <a href="#b-1" class="feature_sub-feature-animate w-inline-block w--current">
        <div class="cms-img-mobile"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 87vw, (max-width: 767px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 87vw, 100vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg 1200w"
            alt=""></div>
        <h2 class="med-title cc-small">Connect dynamic content to any layout</h2>
        <p class="paragraph-gray">You’re not locked into any layout — simply add the elements you want and pull in the data from your CMS.<br></p>
        <div class="feature_sub-feature-line"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="b-2" class="feature_sub-feature-wrap">
      <div class="cms-img-mobile"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 87vw, (max-width: 767px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 87vw, 100vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg 1200w"
          alt=""></div>
      <a href="#b-2" class="feature_sub-feature-animate w-inline-block">
        <h2 class="med-title cc-small">Filter what you display</h2>
        <p class="paragraph-gray">Conditionally display content as needed, sort based on a given field, or hide content you don’t need.<br></p>
        <div class="feature_sub-feature-line"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="b-3" class="feature_sub-feature-wrap cc-bottom">
      <div class="cms-img-mobile"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 87vw, (max-width: 767px) 90vw, (max-width: 991px) 87vw, 100vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg 1200w"
          alt=""></div>
      <a href="#b-3" class="feature_sub-feature-animate w-inline-block">
        <h2 class="med-title cc-small">Build a custom search experience from scratch</h2>
        <p class="paragraph-gray">Design your search experience from scratch — visually — and control exactly what content your site visitors can discover.<br></p>
        <div class="feature_sub-feature-line"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-list_visual-track-copy">
    <div class="feature-alt_visual-wrap">
      <div class="feature-alt_visual">
        <div class="feature_cover"></div>

        <a href="#b-1" class="feature-visual cc-b5 w-inline-block w--current">
          <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, 48vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-500.jpeg 500w, 
                           https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-800.jpeg 800w, 
                           https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, 
                           https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed62032883fbb_05-cms-img-connect.jpg 1200w" alt="" class="feature-image cc-cms"></a>

        <a href="#b-2" class="feature-visual cc-b6 w-inline-block"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, 48vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6720a883fbc_06-cms-img-filter.jpg 1200w"
            alt="" class="feature-image cc-cms"></a>
        <a href="#b-3" class="feature-visual cc-b3 w-inline-block"><img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, 48vw" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5f1efd2768fed6b653883c9d/5f1efd2768fed6c803883fc5_07-cms-img-search.jpg 1200w"
            alt="" class="feature-image cc-cms"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. I doesn't change the image but it is easily to achieve but putting all the images url in an array and changing img url based on `index`

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
let b1 = document.getElementById('b1');
let b2 = document.getElementById('b2');
let b3 = document.getElementById('b3');

if(b1.getBoundingClientRect().y < amountOfPixelFromTop) {
   b1.style.opacity = 1;
   b2.style.opacity = 0.15;
   b3.style.opacity = 0.15;
}
```

And you will do this for the 3 elements when they are in the middle of the page.

Hope that'll help

Comment: if the contents are more than, there be a problem, but thanks for suggesting